# Combining a ExpressJS Router endpoint with a fetch call to an external enpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, download, fetch-api

I am trying to create an Express Router endpoint that will return the CSV file from an external API (Jenkins in this case).

In more detail, what I am trying to achieve is to have a React Frontend call this route on the Express backend and download a CSV file.

**BACKEND**
The Express route is has this structure:

```
router.get('/path/latestCsvTestReport', async (req, res) => {
  const { channel } = req.params;
  return fetch(
      `${jenkinsHost}/job/${channel}/${jenkinsPath}/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/test_result/report_test.csv`, {
        ...fetchOptions,
        headers: { Authorization: jenkinsAuth},
      },
    )
    .then(r => {
          console.log('====== DATA =====', r);
          res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/csv');
          res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
          res.send(r)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // console.log(err);
      res.status(404);
      res.send('report not found');
    });
});
```

and the URL called in the fetch returns a CSV file.

**FRONTEND**

I am calling the Express endpoint from a method on the React frontend using the following function, which utilised the [file-saver library](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/#filesaverjs):

```
async function triggerReportDownload(chlId) {
  console.log('===== CSV Request ====')
  const resource = `/api/jenkins/${chlId}/latestCsvTestReport`;
  saveAs(resource, "report.csv")
}
```

which is triggered by the click of a button on the FrontEnd.

At the moment, the button, triggers a download but the csv downloaded only contains:

> {"size":0 timeout:0}

I am certain I am doing something completely wrong on the way the backend returns the CSV from the fetch call, but for the life of me I do not seem to be able to find the way to formulate the response. Any help/direction towards fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to simply things as possible (being a newbie I had overcomplicated things). So here we are:

**Backend**

Import the ***utils*** library and then create a ***stream***:

```
import util  from 'util';

const streamPipeline = util.promisify(require('stream').pipeline);
```

This is then called from the Express router:

```
router.get('/jenkins/:channel/latestCsvTestReport.csv', async (req, res) => {
  const { channel } = req.params;
  const response = await fetch(
    `${jenkinsHost}/job/${channel}/${jenkinsPath}/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/test_result/report_test.csv`, {
      ...fetchOptions,
      headers: { Authorization: jenkinsAuth },
    },
  );

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=report_test_${Date.now()}.csv`);
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');

  return streamPipeline(response.body, res);
});
```

**Frontend**

Use ***windows.open*** to get the download file

```
async function triggerReportDownload(chlId) {
window.open(`/api/jenkins/${chlId}/latestCsvTestReport.csv`);
}
```